# Retrieving words before certain characters without having to use Perl

Tags: regular-expression, ksh

I have where clauses for SQL queries in text form, and I'd like to extract the column names from them. The clauses can contain conditions like *col_1 = 'Spruce' and col_2 in ('Argentina', 'Cameroon')*.

My first question is, is it possible in ksh to extract *col_1* and *col_2* values from the text (ie. all the words before *`in (`* or an equals sign). I know that in *if-else* conditions it's possible to control the flow of execution if the text matches a given pattern, however I don't know how I could actually retrieve the words that made the text match that particular pattern.

UPDATE:

Eg. if the input is `tree_type = 'Spruce' and country in ('Russia', 'Zambia')`, I'd like to get `tree_type country`.

If the input is `employee_state in ('Colorado', 'Wyoming', 'Louisiana') and dept_nr in (13, 732, 91) and case_code = 82517` I'd like to get `employee_state dept_nr case_code`.

I tried `sed 's/\S\+ \((= \|in (\)/\1/g'`, that removed the words I wanted to keep and kept everything else I wanted removed. I also tried `sed 's/\(\S\+ \)\(= \|in (\)/\1/g'`, this removed `=` and `in (`, but kept everything else.

UPDATE 2:

I piped Costas' first suggestion `sed 's/\S\+ \(= \|in (\)/\1/g'` into a second variable, whose elements I removed from the original one; thus getting what I wanted:

`$ A="employee_state in ('Colorado', 'Wyoming', 'Louisiana') and dept_nr in (13, 732, 91) and case_code = 82517"; B=$(echo $A | sed 's/\S\+ \(= \|in (\)/\1/g'); for b in $B; do A=${A[@]/$b}; done; echo $A`

`employee_state dept_nr case_code`

Costas, I'm most grateful for your help.

Comment: It would be better if you show the few lines of input to provide you the correct answer. There are several command to suitable for you `grep`, `sed` , `awk` ...

Comment: For example `col_2 in ()` are **two** words before a parenthesis but `col_1 =` one only). Or query outputs each value on separate line?

Comment: @Costas thank you, edited the question. Actually I need `col_2` (the word before `in (`) and `col_1` (the word before `=`).

Comment: I guess it could be done, but you have to take into account statements over multiple lines (the `=` sign could be at the beginning of a line), or no spaces between `=` and the value, all sorts of trouble lurking...

Comment: Try to pipe otput via `sed 's/\S\+ = /= /g;s/\S\+ in (/in (/g'`but much better if you show examples of input and desired output.

Comment: A string contains no newlines, so it's not an issue. From `tree_type = 'Maple' and country in ('England', 'Australia')` I'd like to retrieve and array consisting of `tree_type country`.

Comment: @Costas this is good, it removes the column names from the text and leaves everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pipe otput via

```
sed 's/\S\+ \(= \|in (\)/\1/g'
```

Comment: `echo "col_1 = 'Spruce' and col_2 in ('Argentina', 'Cameroon')" | sed 's/\S\+ \((= \|in (\)/\1/g'` results in `= 'Spruce' and in ('Argentina', 'Cameroon')`, which is though the opposite of what I'd like to get, but this is the closest I've got so far to the desired output.

Comment: @AndrásHummer That is why I ask you to show **exact** desired output in example without play in game "What that mean "opposite"?" If you want just words which removed by script you can just add parethesis `sed 's/\(\S\+ \)\(= \|in (\)/\1/g'`

Comment: (note that neither `\S`, `\+` or `\|` are standard, that command won't work outside GNU `sed`)